# Student Assessment

Tags: phd, teaching

I am an academic in physics, i.e. with no formal education in pedagogical methods and teaching yet.

I was reading this paper of Biggs [What the Student Does: teaching for enhanced learning](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/0729436990180105) and *assessment* is often referenced as an integral part of teaching.
The theory expressed in the paper reference the **alignment** between the educational *objectives* and their *assessment*.

But how it should be designed such an assessment? I have a feeling that here assessment is larger than "grading", but I do not grasp exactly its nature.

In other words, what are your strategies, and do you have material regarding student assessment, specifically of advanced students (MSc or PhD level)?

Comment: As you quoted, assessment should be aligned with LOs. Hence, any meaningful strategy should take LOs in account. What are your LOs?

Comment: By "material", what are you expecting? A couple of papers? Or some LO’s? They would not match your course...

Comment: I was looking for papers about the background theory, without it I feel it would be difficult to formulate learning objective which are coherent.

Comment: In short: expect your students aren't studying to learn but to get good grades or pass. Therefore, you need to assess and grade them in a way that to get good grades they need to learn or do what you want them to learn or do. A simple strategy from this: if you want them to learn something, it must be in the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, assessment means more than grading. In the CS community there are people working on Pedagogical Patterns that are applicable to teaching technical subjects (primarily). Within the larger group there has been an international working group that has focused in the last few years on assessment. Here are two papers that this group has produced:

[Patterns for learning from others](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/309651284_Dialogical_assessment_patterns_for_learning_from_others)

and

[Assessment Driven Course Design](https://hillside.net/plop/2015/papers/proceedings/papers/bergin.pdf)(PDF)

Other pedagogical patterns discuss assessment as well as other teaching topics. There is a book available that captures the work of a much larger group of people and a wider range of topics.

[Pedagogical Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1479171824)

In general, Pedagogical Patterns are written to capture expert teaching practice in a way that makes it accessible, along with including information as to why the practices described are, in most cases, best practice. This is similar to what is done with Software Patterns, but in a more general setting. Some, but not all existing pedagogical patterns are specific to fields like CS and there are missing pieces in the corpus due to the general interests of those who write these.

For assessment patterns, one of the key elements is feedback, and often the ability to repeat flawed work. Feedback doesn't mean just a number written on a page. Another is transparency, making it possible for students to know in advance what the criteria are and how to fulfill them.

For learning, what the student does is much more important than what the teacher does. And for *deep* learning, the student needs both practice/reinforcement and feedback. These are fundamental ideas within the pedagogical patterns community and captured in the assessment patterns.

[This question](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/3152/1293) at CSEducators discusses some ideas about a rational approach to teaching and points to other resources.